# Azure .NET API and File Uploads

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I am hosting a simple API developed in .NET 7 and one of the features of the API is to allow a user file to be uploaded.

This works without issues locally, however it fails to upload the file when hosted as a Azure Web App service.

I have created the corresponding folder in wwwroot through the Console in Azure, but no luck.

Strangely, I have some Error handling code which writes text to a log file in the same folder  , this works without issues.

Are there limitations to the type of files / or size of files that can be stored in the app web folder?  Or am I overlooking something else?

Comment: Pls correct me if I misunderstood your aim. And if it makes no sense for you, could you pls put more details on it? Just like what you said, `limitations to the type of files / or size of files` can be test by yourself. By the way, if you want to store plenty of files, I recommend you using Azure Storage Blob, this is design for it. In my test below, I just create a new free Azure web app instance, and just enable app insights for troubleshoot.

Comment: @TinyWang Thanks for your suggestion regarding Storage Blob.  I think is the best way forward for my case.  This is my first deployment on Azure therefore still in the process of familiarising myself with it's architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure but I think it may relate to the target upload folder? Here's my code and it worked for me.

My view to upload file:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="file-1" />
    </div>
    <button id="btn1">upload</button>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            var form = new FormData();
            if ($('#file-1').prop('files').length == 0){
                return;
            }else{
                form.append("name", $('#file-1').prop('files')[0].name);    
                form.append("name1", $('#file-1').val());    
                form.append("file", $('#file-1').prop('files')[0]);    
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/home/getfile',
                //url: 'https://localhost:7113/home/getfile',
                type: 'POST',
                data: form,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,//stop jquery auto convert form type to default x-www-form-urlencoded
                processData: false,
                success: function (d) {
                    alert(d)
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

And my Controller look like this:

```
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
private IWebHostEnvironment Environment;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IWebHostEnvironment _environment)
{
    _logger = logger;
    Environment = _environment;
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> getfileAsync([FromForm] string name, [FromForm] IFormFile file)
{
    string rootPath = this.Environment.WebRootPath;
    try {
        _logger.LogInformation("the root path is :" + rootPath);
        if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + name;
            string uploadFilePath = Path.Combine(rootPath, "images", fileName);

            await using var stream = new FileStream(uploadFilePath, FileMode.Create);
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
    }
    
    return "success:" + rootPath;
}
```

I need to make sure there's an `images` folder in my `wwwroot` folder. As you can see, when we publish it to Azure, the folder path is different.

[image]