# Azure web app mapping not uploading to AzureFiles

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-files

I have a .NET 7 app in a linux environment that has an endpoint "/api/uploads" that accepts a file and saves it to a folder "uploaded". I am trying to get this "uploaded" folder to be mapped to AzureFiles,

I have tried the following mount paths "/uploaded", "wwwroot/uploaded" and "mounts/wwwroot/uploaded" however the files are never saved in AzureFiles but instead are saved to the "wwwroot/uploaded" folder than can be accessed through .scm.azurewebsites.net
[image: Screenshot with my current config]

I also followed these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=portal&pivots=code-windows and still cant get it to work.

When the application starts up I see that the content root path is "/home/site/wwwroot", thats the reason behind my failed attempt with "/mounts/home/site/wwwroot/uploaded"

I have also tried enabling "WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE" according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/faqs-app-service-linux

Comment: Add a screenshot of the mapping config in the Portal to your question.

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to upload the for the path success:/home/site/wwwroot/wwwroot

Reference  @[Tiny Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75615606/azure-net-api-and-file-uploads) @CSharpRocks

```cs
            string rootPath = this.Environment.WebRootPath;
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("the root path is :" + rootPath);
                if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + name;
                    string uploadFilePath = Path.Combine(rootPath, "images", fileName);

                    await using var stream = new FileStream(uploadFilePath, FileMode.Create);
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            }

            return "success:" + rootPath;
        }
```

[image]

- For [web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?pivots=development-environment-vs&tabs=net60) running on Azure App [Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#access-files) Linux followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=visual-studio,managed-identity,roles-azure-portal,sign-in-azure-cli,identity-visual-studio) refence [MS -Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux?tabs=smb311).

[image]

- Make sure that the URL name is replaced with app service name.

[image]

[image]